# Dockerfile or docker image for jboss/openjdk18-rhel7:1.1

Tags: docker, redhat, s2i

Where can I find the docker image (and if possible Dockerfile) for the image jboss/openjdk18-rhel7:1.1

This image is being used in another dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/openjdk18-rhel7:1.1

ENV \

   PATH="$PATH:"/usr/local/s2i""
```

Comment: Its not easy to figure that out. Some developers will not expose their base image and hence you will not be able to find it online. Been there. Your best bet is to look in Dockerhub. Sometimes there will be links to the Github repository from where you can find your dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

By default, that means docker will pull an image from the url `https://hub.docker.com/jboss/openjdk18-rhel7/` but the repository does not seem exist for me.

Perhaps, you could using `https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/base-jdk/` instead from the same maintainer, like so:

`FROM jboss/base-jdk:8`

For Dockerfile, see https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/base-jdk/~/dockerfile/

Comment: I am able to use the provided jdk image. But my query is how to find that image which I have specified in the query. There should be some repository that should be holding that image

Comment: Then you have to check via `docker info`. Just try `docker info | grep -i registry` to see if you are using private registry.